# I'm getting partial file upload errors with file uploads in PHP from iOS and Postman

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, postman, php-7.3

I have a PHP-based API project here inherited from my predecessor who has moved to a different project. Right now, I'm looking into some odd behaviour with uploading files where they are always successful with small files for all three of Android, iOS and Postman but begin to fail just for iOS and Postman but not Android.

We've noticed this happening on our iOS application when working with relatively large files (>100 MB) as well as with Postman. Our Android app seems to work fine, and even managed to upload files of much larger file sizes; upwards of 1GB and more. I've coordinated with our server admin who says that the server configuration is set to a reasonable level. I believe him since our Android app successfully uploaded a far larger video successfully.

I've isolated the issue to the relevant code below:

```
if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name']))
//... Respond with status code 400 an error message.
```

I've did some digging and found that uploads sent from both our iOS app and Postman results in an error code of 3 which means an UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL according to the docs.

What's interesting is that our iOS app and Postman upload the files perfectly fine if working with smaller files such as around 8-20 MB and I'm quite sure it could easily handle much larger files since our Android app was able to successfully upload a massive 1 GB file.

My gut is telling me it has to do with the differences in how Android, Postman and iOS differ in handling file uploads but I'm not sure where to begin or where to ask our mobile app devs (who also inherited their projects) to look.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Server team took a look on their end and has confirmed it's a server configuration issue. I'm not exactly sure of the details but after they said that they fixed the issue, uploads work now.